# Best way to update embedded document in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I migrate my project from mysql to mongodb and have some troubles.

How to update attributes in embedded document in ActiveRecord way? It is possible in mongoid?

```
class Template
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Versioning

    embedded_in :site, :inverse_of => :templates
end

class Site
  embeds_many :templates
end
```

For example:

```
site = Site.find(params[:current_site_id])
template = site.templates.find(params[:id])

template.update_attributes(params[:template])
```

I got:

```
Access to the collection for Template is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.
```

Ok, but how to do it from the root document?

**Edit**:

It looks like Mongoid::Versioning which I use in Template make some troubles. I remove included module and everything works fine.

Comment: what version of mongoid are you using?

Comment: Since templates are an embedded document, if you add `Mongoid::Versioning` to the `Site` model - it will version any changes to embedded documents. Since embedded documents are actually part of the parent document - and not relations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pb with mongoid's versioning with embedded documents, same goes if you are using paranoia mode.
I would suggested deactivating those options for your embedded docs and replicating the functionality yourself if you really need it.

Alex